# Numpy: Axis Parameter in transpose function

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I’ve recently came across a fancy way to reshape a matrix to perform a specific matrix multiplication.

I’m currently trying to wrap my head around why numpy performs this kind of reshaping when axis parameters are given.

Consider a numpy array of shape `A=[1,2,4,4]`. What people do, is to reshape it using `A.transpose(3,2,1,0).reshape(2,-1)`.

A typical transpose in a matrix would turn the rows into columns where the first element of a row become the first element of a column.

Here, the axis parameters or the application in an higher rank tensor somehow change this. Is there a mathematical concept behind the way numpy transposes this kind of array?

Comment: `a_i,j => a_j,i` expresses the 2d transpose with subscripted indices.  Generalize to 3 or 4 indices.

Comment: Does the order of axis matter here? I didn’t check this for now.

Comment: You can change them in any way.  Experiment with something like `np.arange(24).reshape(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: In numpy transpose is easy because it just changes the shape and strides.

Comment: Yeah I got it. It’s just depending on the dimensions.